# Javascript custom input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I need make input field that contain phone numbers. Users can enter 1-10 numbers. I found almost suitable jQuery plugin. But it's searching from pre-existed datas. In my case there aren't any existed database. Users just fill numbers and commas. For example:

99889966, 88554477, 89879856 etc.

Please look below url and suggest me similar plugin which comfortable with my case.

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html

Comment: I think this is a bit off topic. Why not use one of the many validation plugins around? : http://www.google.lk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+validate

Comment: Because it's not about validation. It's more about StackOverflow's tag. You know while asking question, we enter tags. After press "space", works automaticaly enter below field. I'm looking for plugin like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can simply use this code.

```
$("#txtPhNo").keypress(function (event) {
// 32 - Space, 44 - comma, between 47 to 59 are numbers
if (event.which != 32 && event.which != 44 && (event.which < 47 || event.which > 59)) {
event.preventDefault();
}
});
```

This code is very basic. You can do more tricks by adding features to this.

Comment: It's almost what I wanted. But is there any ready for use jQuery plugins?

Answer (score 2):

check out:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: I don't looking for validation. English is not my nature language. Maybe I described wrong. I'm looking for custom input, that enters texts like facebook and stackoverflow's tag.